# How to limit parsing depth using Tinkerpop Frames

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-frames

Hi I have an interface and a corresponding implementation class like:

```
public interface IActor extends VertexFrame {

    @Property(ActorProps.nodeClass)
    public String getNodeClass();

    @Property(ActorProps.nodeClass)
    public void setNodeClass(String str);

    @Property(ActorProps.id)
    public String getId();

    @Property(ActorProps.id)
    public void setId(String id);

    @Property(ActorProps.name)
    public String getName();

    @Property(ActorProps.name)
    public void setText(String text);

    @Property(ActorProps.uuid)
    public String getUuid();

    @Property(ActorProps.uuid)
    public void setUuid(String uuid);

    @Adjacency(label = RelClasses.CoActors, direction = Direction.OUT)
    public Iterable<IActor> getCoactors();
}
```

And I use OrientDB with it that looks something like that. I had similar implementation with Neo4j as well:

```
Graph graph = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/actordb");
FramedGraph<Graph> manager = new FramedGraphFactory().create(graph);
IActor actor = manager.frame(((OrientGraph)graph).getVertexByKey("Actor.uuid",uuid), IActor.class);
```

Above works but the problem is that in this case or similar, because there is a relationship between two vertices of class Actor, there could be potentially a graph loop. Is there a way to define either by Annotation or some other way (e.g through Manager) to stop after x steps for a specific @Adjacency so this won't go forever? If @GremlinGroovy (https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Gremlin-Groovy) annotation is the answer could you please give an example  ?

Comment: There's not enough information to reproduce this issue. Please provide the version of the libraries you're using. (Important, because there is no `getVertexByKey` method in the `com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-orient-graph:2.4.0` library. I suspect your issue could be this: "`getVertexByKey()` does not work" - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3128

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question/problem. (You say "potentially", but haven't actually proven that there's a problem!)

- Is the problem that there is a loop in the Vertex/Frames, and (you think) loading the object will result in an infinite loop?
- Have you been able to prove that there is a problem loading a Vertex/Frame with a loop? (show me the code/problem)

As I understand it, the Pipelines will `lazy-load` objects (only load then when required). The frames (I imagine) only load adjacent frames when requested. Basically, as far as I can tell, theres no problem.

#### Example (Groovy)

```groovy
// create some framed vertices
Person nick = createPerson(name: 'Nick')
Person michail = createPerson(name: 'Michail')

// create a recursive loop
nick.addKnows(michail)
michail.addKnows(nick)

// handles recursion = true!
Person nick2 = framedGraph.getVertex(nick.asVertex().id, Person)
assert nick2.knows.knows.knows.knows.knows.name == 'Michail'
```

Comment: it creates an infinite loop at least in my case with orientdb. Plus I don't want to be fetching the whole graph under it. I want someway to limit the depth that is being returned